# Compiling tcpsplice on a 64-bit machine

Tags: c, linux, rhel

I am trying to compile a small utility called [tcpslice](ftp://ftp.ee.lbl.gov/tcpslice.tar.gz).  It's the typical GNU C application.  When I run `./configure`, here is the output:

```
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-pc-linux-gnuoldld': machine `x86_64-pc' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub x86_64-pc-linux-gnuoldld failed
```

It appears to not support compilation as a 64-bit Linux application.  So I have a few questions:

1. Is it possible to set some flags to compile the application as 32-bit AND be able to run it on my 64-bit operating system?
2. Is it possible to update the configure script to support 64-bit Linux?  If so, will I be making some serious code changes in the .c files as well?
3. I noticed a 64-bit RHEL6 machine on my network has this utility installed and running with an identical version number (1.2a3).  Could I somehow download the source that was used to build it?  I can get access the to RHN if necessary.

Comment: Install the packages called 'libc32' and/or 'gcc32' or something named like this.

Comment: can you not get the tcpslice program from the tcpdump rpm package available via centos rpm repo?  Not sure what version of centos you are running but http://rpm.pbone.net/index.php3/stat/4/idpl/17839287/dir/centos_5/com/tcpdump-3.9.4-15.el5.x86_64.rpm.html is for centos 5 and the src rpm is available for you to compile with.

Comment: This should be moved to `unix.stackexchange.com`

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to set some flags to compile the application as 32-bit AND be  able to run it on my 64-bit operating system?

Yes. [-m32](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compile-32bit-application-using-gcc-64-bit-linux.html) is the option.

> Is it possible to update the configure script to support 64-bit Linux? If so,  will I be making some serious code changes in the .c files as well?

You will have to make some code changes to make a purely 32 bit application work on 64 bit. Here's a [link](http://www.softwarequalityconnection.com/2011/01/10-biggest-issues-for-developers-migrating-32-bit-applications-to-64-bits/) that talks about porting code from 32 bit to 64 bit.

I am sorry, I do not know the answer for your 3rd question.

Hope the little information provided by me helps in some way.

Comment: Thanks for the help.  How can I tell the `./configure` script to use -m32?  `./configure -m32` fails as an unrecognized option, it looks like a gcc flag.

Comment: `./configure CFLAGS=-m32 CXXFLAGS=-m32 LDFLAGS=-m32` But, as I say in my answer, I don't think this will actually solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

You've misinterpreted what the `configure` script is telling you. The solution has nothing to do with CPU bitness.

The error comes down to a too-old version of `config.guess`, which the package creator generated with `libtoolize`. To fix it, you will need to have `libtool` installed, then say:

```
$ libtoolize --force
```

You'll find that `configure` now runs, because `libtoolize` overwrote the tarball version of `config.guess` with one appropriate to your system.

You may run into another problem, a "missing" `bpf.h` file. Just edit `tcpslice.c` and change this line:

```
#include <net/bpf.h>
```

to:

```
#include <pcap-bpf.h>
```

With those two changes, I got `tcpslice` to build on my 64-bit CentOS 5 box.

Answer (score 0):

install following packages :

```
 $apt-get install ia32-libs.
```

for rhel its different :

look at the answer to this question :

[CentOS 64 bit bad ELF interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328250/centos-64-bit-bad-elf-interpreter)

Comment: I'm running CentOS and I installed glibc.i686.  The `./configure` still fails the same way.