# How do I install tcpslice from source, released for fedora, on a mac 64 bit?

Tags: linux, macos, compilation, cross-platform

The newest publicly available tcpslice version 1.2a1 (found on its [github](https://github.com/the-tcpdump-group/tcpslice)) has a bug where it expects 8 bytes for a time field but gets 16 (when in 64 bit). This leads to the error:

```
tcpslice: problems finding end packet of file ./abc1234.bin
```

I got my info for this error from: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=485670

This led me to grab the updated version (1.2a3) from here and try compiling from source: http://pkgs.fedoraproject.org/repo/pkgs/tcpdump/tcpslice-1.2a3.tar.gz/. I *think* this is or close to the actual [patch](https://github.com/openembedded/meta-openembedded/blob/master/meta-networking/recipes-support/tcpdump/tcpslice/tcpslice-1.2a3-time.patch)

HOWEVER, I couldn't ./configure this on my mac because it says (understandably) this:

```
checking build system type... configure: error: cannot guess build type; you must specify one
```

Not one to give up, and becuase I don't wnat to switch over to linux to continue deveolping my wrapper script, I tried to compile like this:

```
./configure --build=i686-pc-linux-gnu
```

This configured and make'd!!! However, its 32 bit which still gives the same error when I run the newly made tcpdump!!

**Is this possible at all, and what other --build type can I use that is for x86_64 bit systems?** No other --build types are compiling for me. I have no idea how to find acceptable build types, and am currently referenceing this: https://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.2/buildstat.html

EDIT: I tried Warren Young's suggestion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899616/compiling-tcpsplice-on-a-64-bit-machine) but libtoolize --force did not remake config.guess, so I manually downloaded the "newest" config.guess from the link on [this page](https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/config_002eguess.html) with curl. However, now ./configure says:

```
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0': machine `x86_64-apple' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub x86_64-apple-darwin15.4.0 failed
```

Am I screwed? Or can I sitll try a default x86_64 -build type (which I still cannot find):

```
checking build system type... Invalid configuration `x86_64': machine `x86_64' not recognized
configure: error: /bin/sh ./config.sub x86_64 failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Welp, the answer was to manually download the newest config.guess and config.sub files from here: https://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/html_node/config_002eguess.html and to overwrite the ones in the tcpslice directory.

However, the same problem still existed. There must be another reason the time issue is happening on the mac because this version of tcpslice worked fine on ubuntu on the same pcap.

Thanks to Warren Young's post in this question for guiding me in the right (though not successful) direction: [Compiling tcpsplice on a 64-bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10899616/compiling-tcpsplice-on-a-64-bit-machine). Guess I'll be using ubuntu to finish my script!