# Android Hello-World compile error: Intellij cannot find aapt

Tags: android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools

I'm trying to get set up with an Android development environment using IntelliJ in Ubuntu 12.04. I create an Android Application Module, but when I try to build, I get the following error:

> android-apt-compiler: Cannot run program "/home/jon/Programs/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aapt": java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory

Several hours of scouring the internet hasn't helped.

By the way, I ran `locate aapt` in the terminal and found that `aapt` is located at `/home/jon/Programs/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt`

Comment: Well, thanks for all the answers guys! 

I switched to the [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) fork, and it's working just fine. But I think the other solutions regarding symlinks or the android-maven-plugin may be more appropriate for other intellij users. 

I suppose this will be fixed in an update in a matter of time...

Answer (score 130):

It appears that the latest update to the r22 SDK release moved aapt and the lib jar from the platform-tools to the build-tools directory.  While we wait for JetBrains to release an update, here's a quick fix using a couple of symbolic links:

From your AndroidSDK/platform-tools directory, run the following:

```
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/aapt aapt
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/lib lib
```

...and IntelliJ should be able to compile as normal.

Comment: Hi, perfect for me too. Just for info: I run Intellij under Windows, you can open a DOS prompt with admin privileges, and run: `mklink  D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\17.0.0\aapt.exe` and  `mklink /D  D:\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\lib D:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\17.0.0\lib`

Comment: Also had to add:
`ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/aidl aidl`

Comment: If you're getting this and executing aapt directly also says file not found, you may be having a 64-bit issue: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328250/centos-64-bit-bad-elf-interpreter)

Comment: @FrancescoPez Doesn't work in XP or in systems using fat32. For WinXP: http://schinagl.priv.at/nt/hardlinkshellext/hardlinkshellext.html

Comment: For Windows 64Bit users like Francesco Pez mentioned just the hint for paths with spaces: put both paths in quotation marks e.g. 

mklink "C:\Program Files\androidsdk\sdk\platform-tools\aapt.exe" "C:\Program Files\androidsdk\sdk\build-tools\android-4.3\aapt.exe"

Answer (score 21):

update your IntelliJ to 12.1.4 by using beta releases as the update channel
[image]

Comment: This did it, however, I had to select EARLY RELEASES, that showed the .4 update then when it restarted I got the 3.x which i denied. (Mac OS X 10.8.x)

Answer (score 12):

In Windows it is enough to copy only `aapt.exe`, `lib\dx.jar` and `dx.bat`

from *build-tools\android-4.2.2*

to

*platform-tools*

Answer (score 10):

The same problem occurred for me with android-studio. But, this probably applies to the IntelliJ IDE as well.

When checking the file location I saw, however, that `aapt` was in the expected location.

In my case the issue was that I was running a 64-bit Ubuntu linux system which cannot execute the 32-bit `aapt` executable.

Installing 32-bit compatibility libraries solved this issue in my case: `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Comment: It seems `ia32-libs` is no longer available for Ubuntu 13.10 and up.

Comment: Add `deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ raring main restricted universe multiverse` to `/etc/sources.list`, then `sudo apt-get update` and then `sudo apt-get install ia32-libs`

Answer (score 6):

i solve it with this to line commands

```
ln -s ~/Programs/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/17.0.0/aapt ~/Programs/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/aapt
ln -s ~/Programs/android-sdk-linux/build-tools/17.0.0/lib ~/Programs/android-sdk-linux/platform-tools/lib
```

Answer (score 3):

I also noticed it.

ADT has been updated and they added this new build-tools where they moved everything.
Intellijidea is not updating paths so it's searching aapt in the old path.

I don't know how to solve it, so let me know if you find a solution...

UPDATE:

I think that you have only 2 options:

1) Use Android Build studio: http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html 
2) Copy (this is dirty but works) all content from build-tools/17.0.0/ to platform-tools/ and it will build

Comment: Ah, an update issue.

Ok, so I just found that Google released [Android Studio](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html), which is a _fork_ of Intellij. Maybe Google expects people switch to [Android](http://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/studio.html) Studio rather than update Intellij?

Comment: Yes they releaed it (take a look at yesterday Google I/O keynote). It's basically JideaCommunity + more focus on android. Then it will be merged with JideaPro (I hope so).

Comment: It's not really a fork, it is based on the Early Access Program build. Once that EAP build becomes mainline IntelliJ it will have the same features Android Studio has.

Answer (score 2):

To complain to Jetbrains, go here: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-107311

I reckon more votes will be a faster fix.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for the tip! On a mac running the Android 4.2.2 SDK, this worked great. You'll just need to update your paths accordingly. E.g.

ln -s ../build-tools/android-4.2.2/lib lib

ln -s ../build-tools/android-4.2.2/aapt aapt

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue but with android-maven-plugin 
and as a variant of your item #2 rather than copying the file(s) I simply created a symbolic/soft link for aapt

```
cd platform-tools
ln -s ../build-tools/17.0.0/aapt ./
```

This approach seemed to get all my builds functioning again.

Answer (score 1):

Clone the android-maven-plugin on GitHub and install it in your repo

> git clone https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin.git
>   cd .../maven-android-plugin/
>   mvn clean install

Then update your pom to use version 3.5.4-SNAPSHOT of the plugin.
Everything should work properly !

Comment: Note, however, that this will fix the maven build, but not the IntelliJ build.  For that, the symbolic link workaround should help until IntelliJ fixes it.

Comment: you should be able to find the android-maven-plugin version somewhere in the IntelliJ conf...

Comment: the built-in IntelliJ build system doesn't use android-maven-plugin.  To make it work, you'd need to do the symbolic links.  And if you do the symbolic links, you shouldn't need to update to the latest snapshot of android-maven-plugin; the links will fix both the IntelliJ build and the non-latest version of android-maven-plugin.

Comment: Yes, I have a windows environment.  Start a DOS window as administrator, then use the mklink command.  Go to platform-tools, then create links for aapt.exe, aidl.exe, dexdump.exe, dx.bat, and lib\dx.jar to their counterparts in build-tools\17.0.0 and build-tools\17.0.0\lib.  Note: you'll need to create the lib subfolder under platform-tools.

Answer (score 0):

I ran these three commands and my problem was resolved

```
mklink "%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\aapt.exe" "%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\17.0.0\aapt.exe"

mklink /D "%ANDROID_HOME%\platform-tools\lib" "%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\17.0.0\lib"

mklink "%ANDROID_HOME%\platforms\android-17\tools" "%ANDROID_HOME%\build-tools\17.0.0\aidl.exe"
```

If you haven't set ANDROID_HOME Environmental variable the replace %ANDROID_HOME% with the path to your android SDK e.g. C:\Android\android-sdk

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS you need to

```
$ cd platform-tools
$ ln -s ../build-tools/android-4.2.2/aapt aapt
$ ln -s ../build-tools/android-4.2.2/lib lib
```

Answer (score 0):

Goodlife once again.
Just incase of such an error clean project and you are good to go.