# trigger.io [Error 5] Access is denied

Tags: trigger.io, access-denied

I just recently updated to the new version of forge, did not change anything on my setting and when I went to build my app I got an error that said it could not find the file..

so I made the copy of aapt file and put it in a directory where trigger said it was looking (the docs said trigger.io should have moved this file for me already but Im guessing it did not)

After I moved this file and ran the build again it looked like it found the file but now I get [Error 5] Access is denied.

I have checked the permissions on the folder as I am the admin and I have full permissions and I have launched trigger as an administrator and still nothing.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the cause here is that the r22 SDK release moved aapt and the lib jar from the platform-tools to the build-tools directory:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/16592563/126600

Comment: Could you try the fix in that other post and comment here if it works for you?

Comment: Hi Amir, I solved it by updating the python script to add the exe, not sure if this is the best way but it seemed to work for me. the answer is below

Comment: I was having this exact issue and your answer worked for me as well. Saved my day!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So again from what I can tell this is a problem with the python script that calls aapt.

When you look at the script it points only to aapt, this means its looking for a directory and not the aapt.exe file itself so the first thing that happens is

1) forge says it cant find the aapt directory, this is why you are getting the error message "cant find aapt tool"

2) by adding the directory you would get the access denied because then the script is trying to run all these commands on just the directory (this was the problem I ran into), by making the change below you do not need to create a directory, just leave everything how it is but add the exe and it should work

After doing some testing I found that by adding .exe to the pythong script in android_tasks.py the build was able to run successfully

if you look on line 35 of android_tasks.py and change 'appt' to 'appt.exe' it should build for you

this is what it looks like for me

path.join(sdk, 'build-tools', '*','aapt.exe')
Hope this helps