# Android Studio not compiling

Tags: java, android, compilation, android-studio

I'm having an issue that's taking me since yesterday morning to figure it out with no success. I'm really desperate right now to solve this.

In the log console, at the bottom of the Android-Studio window I get this error:

```
Error: Gradle: Execution failed for task':MyApplication2:mergeDebugResources'.
         >java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/user/.local/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/android-4.2.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
```

But happens that the file is there. I've done some research with no success. I'm taking so much time on this. I don't know why this should be wrong. I'm on Linux.

Please help me resolving this issue.

EDIT:

On Processing IDE the exact same error happens:

```
BUILD FAILED
/home/user/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:649: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/home/user/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/tools/ant/build.xml:690: Execute failed: java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "/home/user/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/build-tools/18.0.1/aapt" (in directory "/tmp/android8933435574063638939sketch"): java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
```

Comment: Are you running eclipse from the same user? Does it have correct permissions to access that file?

Comment: Sir, I've installed Eclipse before but I uninstalled it since I do prefer NetBeans. At the time I didn't have the Android SDK so I can't answer that. But I can tell you that Processing IDE has the same problem, it doesn't compile because of that same error, as you can see on the Edit of my question.

Comment: Is the android sdk in your PATH?

Comment: The Path to put the app is: /home/user/sketchbook. I don't know if I'm answering to your question. I'm new to Linux and specially new to Java and Android. I used to program in C/C++. I hope my answer helps to figure out some problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try to install the following:
sudo apt-get --no-install-recommends install ia32-libs-multiarch

Comment: Had exactly the same problem as the author of this thread. This answer does solve the problem. Thank you.