# Jenkins Build error FileNotFound / Permission denied

Tags: android, jenkins, build.xml

after a lot of tutorials regarding jenkins and android I still got stuck in having an error free build.

I did follow these tutorials: 
http://www.vogella.com/articles/Jenkins/article.html
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+an+Android+app+and+test+project

The only difference to my setup is that I'm not checking out from a repository.
I have the code imported in the job itself, so in my "jobs" directory I do have a workspace with 2 projects (normal android and androidUnitTest project).

When trying to build I got this log:

```
-build-setup:
[getbuildtools] Using latest Build Tools: 18.0.1
     [echo] Resolving Build Target for MainActivity...
[gettarget] Project Target:   Android 4.0
[gettarget] API level:        14
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Creating output directories if needed...
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Resolving Dependencies for MainActivity...
[dependency] Library dependencies:
[dependency] No Libraries
[dependency] 
[dependency] ------------------
[dependency] API<=15: Adding annotations.jar to the classpath.
[dependency] WARNING: unable to write jarlist cache file /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Jenkins4AndroidTest/workspace/XJenkins/bin/jarlist.cache
     [echo] ----------
     [echo] Building Libraries with 'debug'...
   [subant] No sub-builds to iterate on

-code-gen:
[mergemanifest] Found Deleted Target File
[mergemanifest] Merging AndroidManifest files into one.
[mergemanifest] Manifest merger disabled. Using project manifest only.'
```

resulting in this error:

```
/Users/Shared/android-sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:644: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Jenkins4AndroidTest/workspace/XJenkins/bin/AndroidManifest.xml (Permission denied)
        at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
```

Seems to me like it ignores the relative path I used at `Invoke Ant` ("./XJenkins/build.xml", target: debug)

Does anyone have any hint, tip or solution for this? That'll be really great!

EDIT:
I previously had the situation where I had a different error (I used some more parameters for ant as mentioned in the tutorial.) The error was this: `/Users/Shared/android-sdks/tools/ant/build.xml:392: Problem: failed to create task or type checkenv` ... would that be a better approach?

Comment: `unable to write jarlist cache file` suggests that either you don't have that file, either you don't have rights. Try to move the SDK to a different location where you have write rights.

Comment: I do have the sdk under /shared and have 777 rights on it, shouldn't that be enough?

Comment: `java.io.FileNotFoundException: /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Jenkins4AndroidTest/workspace/XJenkins/bin/AndroidManifest.xml (Permission denied)` seems to me self-explanatory

Comment: Where do you have Jenkins installed?

Comment: FileNotFound: the file DOES exist - 
Permission denied: rights are 777, should work - 
Jenkins installed: "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/" - 
next try: configuring some users

Comment: Seems like this could be related to my issue: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18253544/android-processing-build-not-compiling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to me a problem of ownership of the source.

Go to : `/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/jobs/Jenkins4AndroidTest/workspace/XJenkins/bin/`
and perform and : `ls -rtl`

You should see something like that :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 jenkins jenkins AndroidManifest.xml
```

If not, give the right to jenkins to it with **chown** command.
I will personnaly do it on all directory

```
sudo chown -R jenkins:jenkins /Users/Shared/Jenkins
```

This command will give ownership of ALL CONTENT within Jenkins directory to Jenkins User.

**BE CAREFUL : This is assuming that Jenkins is launched as a service with User Jenkins. 
If you launch jenkins as a webapp on tomcat7 for instance, Jenkins user will be tomcat7 and you shall grand tomcat7 with ownership**