# Android Studio: android-19 not found, but it's clearly installed

Tags: android-studio

I've tried rebuilds, opening/closing android studio, switching to api level 18 and everything: I get this output:

Error:Module 'LabsCore': platform 'android-19' not found.
Error:Module 'facebook': platform 'android-19' not found.

In the sdk manager it is really all installed, I checked multiple times. Is this an issue with android studio/gradle plugin in the latest version?

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same error after updrade to Android Studio 0.5.3/0.5.4. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22761027/android-studio-update-0-5-3-platform-android-19-not-found). And [the cholm's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22808375/534698) that was the solution for me.