# Gradle Build Error on Android Studio in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: android, ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, android-gradle-plugin

Well, after too much googling for about two days and trying most of the recommended work arounds suggested on this platform, my problem is not solved yet!!

It goes like this...

I have started android app development recently with Android Studio on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
Whenever I open my project, gradle build always finishes with following two errors;-

```
Executing tasks: [clean, :app:compileDebugJava]

Configuration on demand is an incubating feature.
:app:clean
:app:preBuild
:app:preDebugBuild
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl
:app:compileDebugRenderscript
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources
:app:mergeDebugResources
/home/vivek/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/vivek/Documents/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/21.0.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory
:app:mergeDebugResources FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> /home/vivek/AndroidStudioProjects/MyApplication3/app/src/main/res/drawable-mdpi/ic_launcher.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/vivek/Documents/android-studio/sdk/build-tools/21.0.1/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 6.776 secs
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Hello-World compile error: Intellij cannot find aapt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588969/android-hello-world-compile-error-intellij-cannot-find-aapt)

Comment: You could try to explain how did you tried to solve the problem.

Comment: @Curios_Tom If you have a 64bit system you need to install some 32 bit libraries. You can try `sudo apt-get install libc6:i386 libncurses5:i386 libstdc++6:i386`. If that does not work install `ia32-libs` package instead.

Comment: I tried 'ia32-libs' but it says "you have unmet dependencies". And 'libstdc++6:i386' went fine but it doesn't seem to be resolving the errror.