# Android Studio 1.0.2 fails build Build tools revision 21.1.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 64bit OS

Tags: ubuntu, android-studio, aapt, build-tools

So there are a few posts I have read with exact same problem as [Android studio 1.0.2 not building app:mergeDebugResources error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27589844/android-studio-1-0-2-not-building-appmergedebugresources-error)

but none of them seem to work for me and I was wondering if anyone else has issue with installing Android Development Studio for the first time on ubuntu 14.04 x64 bit OS and has found a solution.

I tried running

```
sudo apt-get install lib32stdc++6
sudo apt-get install lib32z1
```

but I still get same error:

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'. /home/user_name/AndroidStudioProjects/project_name/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png: Error: Cannot run program "/home/user_name/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory Error:Error: Cannot run program "/home/user_name/Android/Sdk/build-tools/21.1.2/aapt": error=2, No such file or directory /home/user_name/AndroidStudioProjects/project_name/app/src/main/res/drawable-hdpi/ic_launcher.png

I even tried the suggestions on  [Android Hello-World compile error: Intellij cannot find aapt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16588969/android-hello-world-compile-error-intellij-cannot-find-aapt) but none resolved my issue :( any help greatly appreciated, would have thought android would have been more out of the box to setup on linux

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok a work around was to lower the build tools version used.  This can be done in the Android Studio under

File>Project Structure

Click on the "app" option on left hand menu and select the 20.0.0 build tools and no errors seen on building basic hello world project.