# p7zip 64 bit binary

Tags: linux, download, 7zip, centos7

Can anyone help me find a 64 bit binary of 7z for linux?
I have tried downloading what is there on their website i.e. from this [link](http://sourceforge.net/projects/p7zip/files/p7zip/9.20.1/). But it is 32-bit binary and it doesn't work on CentOs 64 bit. On CentOs 64 bit I get a following error message : `/lib/ld-linux.so.2: bad ELF interpreter: No such file or directory`. I have read [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8328250/centos-64-bit-bad-elf-interpreter) regarding this error and I don't want to use 32 bit library support as mentioned there. Instead I am searching for 64 bit 7z binary.

Comment: Here? http://rpmfind.net/linux/rpm2html/search.php?query=7z.so%28%29%2864bit%29

Comment: that's an installable..I want copy paste binary.

Answer (score 3):

Here you have:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/fecvcjs8zs2litp/p7zip-binary-64bit.zip

I simply downloaded a 64-bit RPM package of p7zip and extracted it with 7zip for Windows to get the binaries.

Don't forget to chmod +x the "7za" file.

Comment: thanks for the link although I had already downloaded the sources and built it myself

Comment: It was not easy to find a build of v16.02 that works with the old C runtime libraries of a CentOS6-like Linux. [This gist](https://gist.github.com/P7h/9fcccc54596ad05764128dec6f6cf78d) helped me to find one.