# Debian Stretch and Jessie 32-bit libraries

Tags: c++, x86, debian, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit

For those looking for the answer, there it's, as it's not clear on other websites.

This is required at least by the Intel compiler. Maybe it helps also for other software.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just run those commands in your terminal.

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install build-essential gcc-multilib rpm libstdc++6:i386 libgcc1:i386 zlib1g:i386 libncurses5:i386
```

Or as root remove the "sudo" from them.